# compute length string of variable with cobol

Tags: cobol

I have a NOTE in database table
How can i calculate the length of that string?

I have a variable defined like

```
10 NOTE.
    49 NOTE-LEN          PIC S9(4) USAGE COMP.
    49 NOTE-TEXT         PIC X(500).
```

Note is a string of 500 characters.
I want to compute the note length.

Comment: check this http://www.geekinterview.com/talk/6230-find-out-the-actual-length-string.html

Comment: @Satya that thread is not very robust. What about embedded blanks? For text up to 500 bytes, I'd expect some somewhere.

Comment: You may want to check my updated answer if going for the `RESVERSE`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a common way:

```
MOVE ZERO TO count-of-trailing-spaces                                     

INSPECT FUNCTION REVERSE ( NOTE-TEXT )                       
   TALLYING count-of-trailing-spaces                                        
   FOR LEADING SPACE

SUBTRACT count-of-trailing-spaces                                     
  FROM LENGTH OF ( NOTE-TEXT )
  GIVING NOTE-LEN
```

`FUNCTION REVERSE` will swap the bytes of a field into reverse order. `INSPECT` does not have `TALLYING ... TRAILING` (except in compilers from some vendors, but it is non-standard) so `INSPECT ... LEADING ...` can be used once the field is reversed.

Sometimes I should take my irony hat off. If using the `FUNCTION REVERSE`, also check the field for space first, there is no point in reversing 500 spaces and then counting 500 leading spaces.

Also "know your data". If notes are mostly short, and you do a lot of them, you might want to investigate whether something more speedy is required. It depends on your data and hardware as to whether there's a benefit to be had from that, but bear it in mind.

It may be worth investigating whether something up the line actually *knows* how long the field is, and can already tell you.

I'd just loop from the back, counting spaces (after first checking for all space). Less strain on the CPU. One way to do that:

```
IF NOTE-TEXT EQUAL TO SPACE
    MOVE ZERO TO NOTE-LEN
ELSE
    MOVE LENGTH OF NOTE-TEXT TO NOTE-LEN
    PERFORM 
      UNTIL NOTE-TEXT-BYTE ( NOTE-LEN ) 
        NOT EQUAL TO SPACE
          SUBTRACT +1 FROM NOTE-LEN
    END-PERFORM
END-IF
```

Of course this requires a defintion of `NOTE-TEXT-BYTE` as being a constituent of `NOTE-TEXT`.

The 49-level is probably significant, so can't do it so neatly:

```
49  NOTE-TEXT         PIC X(500).
49  NOTE-TEXT-BYTE
      REDEFINES NOTE-TEXT
      OCCURS 500      PIC X.
```

Perhaps the 49s provide some case for reference-modification. Perhaps not.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU Cobol

```
FUNCTION LENGTH(FUNCTION TRIM(note-text TRAILING))
```

with the caveat that zero-length items were ill defined until COBOL 2014 was published.  FUNCTION TRIM will always return at least one space for an all space field.  That will likely change in the not too distant future now that zero-length items have been defined in the standard.

Comment: As with the others, it can be within an `IF` that tests for `SPACE`. Neat, clear. Confirm with representative data/volume that it won't make the CPU melt, and it'll be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my favorite:

```
If Note-Text > Spaces
    Perform Varying    Note-Len from Length of Note-Text by -1
      Until Note-Text (Note-Len: 1) > Space
    End-Perform
Else
    Move Zero to Note-Len
End-If
```

Comment: I see that trailing values less than space will quietly disappear. I have never understood the penchant for `> space(s)`

Comment: Bill, of course you are right. I assumed Note-Text will only consist of displayable 1 byte-characters, otherwise it would not be clear, what Note-Len should be.

Comment: Yes, so did I :-) It's just that if it doesn't, you'll see all mine, and I can't think of a reason not to do that (unless the spec says "drop out out trailing spaces and non-displayable characters"). I just don't see why the `>/< SPACE(S)` is so popular. Someone, somewhere must have stated it...

Answer (score -2):

```
INSPECT FUNCTION REVERSE ( NOTE-TEXT )                       
   TALLYING count-of-trailing-spaces                                        
   FOR LEADING SPACE

SUBTRACT count-of-trailing-spaces                                     
  FROM LENGTH OF NOTE-TEXT
  GIVING NOTE-LEN
```

Note:
`LENGTH OF (NOTE-TEXT) -> For LENGTH OF` function () is not required.

Comment: This not an answer to the question. It is a comment to the accepted answer that parentheses are not required for `LENGTH OF`.